# Is it true that all the infallibles are destined to receive martyrdom?

Tags: source-identification, shiism, belief

It is a commonly held belief (observed from the words of imams (sermons)/speakers of religious gatherings), that all the [fourteen infallibles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fourteen_Infallibles) are destined to receive martyrdom.

Is that true?

If yes, then why is it so?

And what is the source of this belief, or — if I am not literally wrong — rule?

**(Shia View)**

Comment: No, Muhammad was a infallible, but didn't receive martyrdom. Where does you see this belief?

Comment: e.g. u can read the mentioned site (in Arabic, French, Turkish & Urdu) regarding the martyrdom of the Prophet(s)as the confirmation of Dear Bleeding-Fingers: http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa4348 (Aravic)  ___   http://www.islamquest.net/fr/archive/question/fa4348 (French) _________ http://www.islamquest.net/tr/archive/question/fa4348 (Turkish) _____ http://www.islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa4348 (Urdu)   __ unfortunately I couldnt find it in other famous languages like English, Germany,...)

Comment: so you could give a small explanation of that here  in english... Highly expected... @السید____علی

Comment: Oh, to be honest, there should be some relatively detailed issues in order to persuade… In truth, occasionally it won’t be simple to persuade the addressee by a brief explanation. Anyhow, as far as possible (not surely) I’d put a brief matter (if I could), otherwise… /  What about other languages such as: Indonesia, Melayu, Farsi? If no, hopefully later… (Of course do not say a certain promise, due to the limitation of the time…). Good luck.

Comment: @SepidehBakhoda This believe is a Shia believe not Sunni, something which the OP failed to make clear, which might be why you don't know of it.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding the Shi' believe imamate can only be with the complete pure, thereby the Imam must be infallible. As the imam in effect give their life in servitude and lead the ummah, in the hereafter they will also carry a rank (to identify them). This has been equated to Shaheed.

Generally Shaheed is translated as Matyr, but it actually refers to the one who has witnessed. And Shi' believe the Imamas have witnessed.

Comment: We are not a site for argument and debate: Answers here are expected to be unbiassed and focussed on the actual question asked, not a vehicle for  inserting alternate points of view or "proving" which perspective is "more correct".